# How to show uploaded image to CGridView and Table in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have uploaded images into my project folder. But I cannot show it in the:
1. CGridVIew
[image]

2. Table
   [image]

Can anyone teach me how to do it?? Thanks all

And this is my code in views/barang/admin

```
<?php
/* @var $this BarangController */
/* @var $model Barang */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Barang'=>array('index'),
'Manajemen Barang',
);

$this->menu=array(
array('label'=>'Daftar Barang', 'url'=>array('index')),
array('label'=>'Tambah Data Barang', 'url'=>array('create')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
$('.search-form').toggle();
return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
$.fn.yiiGridView.update('barang-grid', {
    data: $(this).serialize()
});
return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Manajemen Barang</h1>

<p>Kalo mau nyari di kotak pencarian bisa dengan tambahin ini: (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>,     <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b>, <b>=</b>) gan </p>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Pencarian Lanjut','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'barang-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id_barang',
    'nama_barang',
    'id_merk',
    'harga',
    'foto',
    /*
    'deskripsi',
    */
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Hi, I have enter the code of my admin.php in here. Is that you need to see? If no, I will update the controller and the model. Thanks

Comment: Post your code and I can show you.

Comment: hello, Pitchinnate, I have posted my code admin.php I really hope you can teach me. Thanks

Comment: So you want `foto` to actually show the image correct?

Comment: read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail

Comment: yes Pitchinnate, how to do that??
Hey, thanks Ionut Flavius Pogacian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this edited version of your code.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
          'id'=>'barang-grid',
          'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
          'filter'=>$model,
          'columns'=>array(
             'id_barang',
             'nama_barang',
             'id_merk',
             'harga',
             array(
              'type' => 'raw',
              'value' => 'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/barang/" . $data->foto)'

           ),
           array(
               'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
           ),
       ),
    )); ?>
```

Comment: really I thank you very much Mr. Joe. Next, how to resize it, example I want to resize it 150x150. Thanks you very much

Comment: lol, you'll have to try and work that one out yourself, I'm off to cook dinner. Good luck with your resizing!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl . "/images/barang/" . $data->foto',
                  "alt tag fo foo",
                  array("width"=>"150px" ,"height"=>"150px"));
```